# why TCP session is closed when A6/AI GSM connected to mqtt server immediately?

Tags: gsm, microsoft-windows-iot, eclipse-iot

I use A6/AI GSM module to connect mqtt broker through cellular network. it can open tcp session to server but the session terminate immediately. and gsm try to open tcp session again and session closed again and it keep in this loop. so what should i do?? here what i get

[image: response received from A6/AI GSM]

[image: that's debug output]

```cpp
// Select your modem:
#define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM800
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM808
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM868
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM900
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM7000
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM7000SSL
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM7080
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM5360
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM7600
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_UBLOX
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SARAR4
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_M95
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_BG96
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_A6
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_A7
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_M590
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_MC60
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_MC60E
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_ESP8266
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_XBEE
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SEQUANS_MONARCH

// Set serial for debug console (to the Serial Monitor, default speed 115200)
#define SerialMon Serial

// Set serial for AT commands (to the module)
// Use Hardware Serial on Mega, Leonardo, Micro
#ifndef __AVR_ATmega328P__
#define SerialAT Serial1

// or Software Serial on Uno, Nano
#else
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial SerialAT(2, 3);  // RX, TX
#endif

// See all AT commands, if wanted
// #define DUMP_AT_COMMANDS

// Define the serial console for debug prints, if needed
#define TINY_GSM_DEBUG SerialMon

// Range to attempt to autobaud
// NOTE:  DO NOT AUTOBAUD in production code.  Once you've established
// communication, set a fixed baud rate using modem.setBaud(#).
#define GSM_AUTOBAUD_MIN 9600
#define GSM_AUTOBAUD_MAX 115200

// Add a reception delay, if needed.
// This may be needed for a fast processor at a slow baud rate.
// #define TINY_GSM_YIELD() { delay(2); }

// Define how you're planning to connect to the internet.
// This is only needed for this example, not in other code.
#define TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS true
#define TINY_GSM_USE_WIFI false

// set GSM PIN, if any
#define GSM_PIN ""

// Your GPRS credentials, if any
const char apn[]      = "YourAPN";
const char gprsUser[] = "";
const char gprsPass[] = "";

// Your WiFi connection credentials, if applicable
const char wifiSSID[] = "YourSSID";
const char wifiPass[] = "YourWiFiPass";

// MQTT details
const char* broker = "broker.hivemq.com";

const char* topicLed       = "GsmClientTest/led";
const char* topicInit      = "GsmClientTest/init";
const char* topicLedStatus = "GsmClientTest/ledStatus";

#include <TinyGsmClient.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

// Just in case someone defined the wrong thing..
#if TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS && not defined TINY_GSM_MODEM_HAS_GPRS
#undef TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS
#undef TINY_GSM_USE_WIFI
#define TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS false
#define TINY_GSM_USE_WIFI true
#endif
#if TINY_GSM_USE_WIFI && not defined TINY_GSM_MODEM_HAS_WIFI
#undef TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS
#undef TINY_GSM_USE_WIFI
#define TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS true
#define TINY_GSM_USE_WIFI false
#endif

#ifdef DUMP_AT_COMMANDS
#include <StreamDebugger.h>
StreamDebugger debugger(SerialAT, SerialMon);
TinyGsm        modem(debugger);
#else
TinyGsm        modem(SerialAT);
#endif
TinyGsmClient client(modem);
PubSubClient  mqtt(client);

#define LED_PIN 13
int ledStatus = LOW;

uint32_t lastReconnectAttempt = 0;

void mqttCallback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int len) {
  SerialMon.print("Message arrived [");
  SerialMon.print(topic);
  SerialMon.print("]: ");
  SerialMon.write(payload, len);
  SerialMon.println();

  // Only proceed if incoming message's topic matches
  if (String(topic) == topicLed) {
    ledStatus = !ledStatus;
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, ledStatus);
    mqtt.publish(topicLedStatus, ledStatus ? "1" : "0");
  }
}

boolean mqttConnect() {
  SerialMon.print("Connecting to ");
  SerialMon.print(broker);

  // Connect to MQTT Broker
  boolean status = mqtt.connect("GsmClientTest");

  // Or, if you want to authenticate MQTT:
  // boolean status = mqtt.connect("GsmClientName", "mqtt_user", "mqtt_pass");

  if (status == false) {
    SerialMon.println(" fail");
    return false;
  }
  SerialMon.println(" success");
  mqtt.publish(topicInit, "GsmClientTest started");
  mqtt.subscribe(topicLed);
  return mqtt.connected();
}


void setup() {
  // Set console baud rate
  SerialMon.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);

  // !!!!!!!!!!!
  // Set your reset, enable, power pins here
  // !!!!!!!!!!!

  SerialMon.println("Wait...");

  // Set GSM module baud rate
  TinyGsmAutoBaud(SerialAT, GSM_AUTOBAUD_MIN, GSM_AUTOBAUD_MAX);
  // SerialAT.begin(9600);
  delay(6000);

  // Restart takes quite some time
  // To skip it, call init() instead of restart()
  SerialMon.println("Initializing modem...");
  modem.restart();
  // modem.init();

  String modemInfo = modem.getModemInfo();
  SerialMon.print("Modem Info: ");
  SerialMon.println(modemInfo);

#if TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS
  // Unlock your SIM card with a PIN if needed
  if (GSM_PIN && modem.getSimStatus() != 3) { modem.simUnlock(GSM_PIN); }
#endif

#if TINY_GSM_USE_WIFI
  // Wifi connection parameters must be set before waiting for the network
  SerialMon.print(F("Setting SSID/password..."));
  if (!modem.networkConnect(wifiSSID, wifiPass)) {
    SerialMon.println(" fail");
    delay(10000);
    return;
  }
  SerialMon.println(" success");
#endif

#if TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS && defined TINY_GSM_MODEM_XBEE
  // The XBee must run the gprsConnect function BEFORE waiting for network!
  modem.gprsConnect(apn, gprsUser, gprsPass);
#endif

  SerialMon.print("Waiting for network...");
  if (!modem.waitForNetwork()) {
    SerialMon.println(" fail");
    delay(10000);
    return;
  }
  SerialMon.println(" success");

  if (modem.isNetworkConnected()) { SerialMon.println("Network connected"); }

#if TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS
  // GPRS connection parameters are usually set after network registration
  SerialMon.print(F("Connecting to "));
  SerialMon.print(apn);
  if (!modem.gprsConnect(apn, gprsUser, gprsPass)) {
    SerialMon.println(" fail");
    delay(10000);
    return;
  }
  SerialMon.println(" success");

  if (modem.isGprsConnected()) { SerialMon.println("GPRS connected"); }
#endif

  // MQTT Broker setup
  mqtt.setServer(broker, 1883);
  mqtt.setCallback(mqttCallback);
}

void loop() {
  // Make sure we're still registered on the network
  if (!modem.isNetworkConnected()) {
    SerialMon.println("Network disconnected");
    if (!modem.waitForNetwork(180000L, true)) {
      SerialMon.println(" fail");
      delay(10000);
      return;
    }
    if (modem.isNetworkConnected()) {
      SerialMon.println("Network re-connected");
    }

#if TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS
    // and make sure GPRS/EPS is still connected
    if (!modem.isGprsConnected()) {
      SerialMon.println("GPRS disconnected!");
      SerialMon.print(F("Connecting to "));
      SerialMon.print(apn);
      if (!modem.gprsConnect(apn, gprsUser, gprsPass)) {
        SerialMon.println(" fail");
        delay(10000);
        return;
      }
      if (modem.isGprsConnected()) { SerialMon.println("GPRS reconnected"); }
    }
#endif
  }

  if (!mqtt.connected()) {
    SerialMon.println("=== MQTT NOT CONNECTED ===");
    // Reconnect every 10 seconds
    uint32_t t = millis();
    if (t - lastReconnectAttempt > 10000L) {
      lastReconnectAttempt = t;
      if (mqttConnect()) { lastReconnectAttempt = 0; }
    }
    delay(100);
    return;
  }

  mqtt.loop();
}
```

Comment: sorry @jsotola, but I use tiny gsm library example for MQTT client. that's what I get. i don't know why this behavior occur.

Comment: so what should I do should i add the full code here, cause i don't know why this problem exist!!!

Comment: I show you what I get on the serial. include text of what I get won't help.

Comment: the code prints many messages to serialMon ... it would help to see where it may be hanging up the connection

Comment: @jsotola this where the communication is hanged at MQTT NOT CONNECTED. the other image is received response from gsm. i put it to help to get pic of what received from gsm.